# Как исправить алгоритм ML k-ближайших соседей (kNN)?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow, scikit-learn

Есть код k-ближайших соседей (kNN) и набор данных, разбитый на два набора (для обучения (X, Y) и проверки (x_test, y_test)). А также условие `y_knn_filt = np.max(knn.predict_proba(x_test), axis=1) == 1`, для прогнозирования меток классов только для тех выборок из x_test, у которых два ближайших соседа `n_neighbors=2` имеют одинаковые метки.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1, weights='distance').fit(X, Y)
y_knn = knn.predict(x_test)
print('все предсказания', y_knn)

y_knn_filt = np.max(knn.predict_proba(x_test), axis=1) == 1
print('фильтр уверенных предсказаний', y_knn_filt)
print('только уверенные предсказания', np.array(y_knn)[y_knn_filt])
AA = accuracy_score(a[y_test], y_knn)
print('score по всем предсказаниям', AA)
AA_filt = accuracy_score(np.array(y_test)[y_knn_filt], np.array(y_knn)[y_knn_filt])
print('score по уверенным предсказаниям', AA_filt)
```

Либо добавлял вот такое условие для определения одинаковости меток у ближайших соседей:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2).fit(X)
AA = neigh.kneighbors(x_test)
print(AA)
for i in AA[1]:       
   if np.unique(Y[i]).size == 1:
       print('da', Y[i])
   else:
       print('net')
```

Проблема, не могу эти условия (условия по прогнозированию меток только для тех выборок, у которых ближайшие соседи имею одинаковые метки) переписать для kNN с перекрестной проверкой `"Все кроме одного" -  from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut`

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1, weights='distance').fit(X, Y)
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, Y, cv=LeaveOneOut())
print(scores.mean())
```

Кто-нибудь знает как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LeaveOneOut` просто предоставляет вам последовательность `train/test` наборов, вы можете итерироваться по ним, делать `fit`, `predict` и вычислять `score` внутри цикла по этим наборам:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
score_list = []
loo = LeaveOneOut()
skipped = 0
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_knn = knn.predict(X_test)
    y_knn_filt = np.max(knn.predict_proba(X_test), axis=1) == 1
    if not any(y_knn_filt):
      skipped += 1
      continue
    score = accuracy_score(np.array(y_test)[y_knn_filt], np.array(y_knn)[y_knn_filt])
    score_list.append(score)
print(np.mean(score_list))
print('пропущено', skipped, 'неуверенных сэмплов из', X.shape[0])
```

Постарайтесь на будущее использовать в коде `X` *большое*, потому что это *матрица*, и `y` *маленькое*, потому что это *вектор*. Так принято. :)

UPDATE: Добавил в ответ проверку, что нашлось хотя бы одно "уверенное" предсказание. С учётом того, что LeaveOneOut выдаёт по всему одному тестовому сэмплу, вероятность того, что этот сэмпл окажется неуверенным предсказанием и score придётся считать от пустого множества, очень велико и такие случаи надо пропускать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105830/discussion-on-answer-by-crazyelf----ml-k--).