# Помогите посчитать значение q2 для Leave-One-Out перекрестной проверки линейной регрессии?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Имеется вот такой код:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Porphs_data = pd.read_excel('I:\\Porphyrins\\26_4-Descs_varI_22-3-20.xlsx', index_col=0)
y = Porphs_data.LogFi
X = Porphs_data.drop(['LogFi'], axis=1)
# Select upper triangle of correlation matrix
upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
# Find index of feature columns with correlation greater than 0.95
to_drop = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] > 0.95)]
# Drop features 
X = X.drop(Porphs_data[to_drop], axis=1)
X_train = X.drop(["(p-Br)4-TPP", "5,10-NO2-etioporphyrin I", "Deuteroporphyrin-IX-DME", 
                  "N-CH3-Octaethylporphyrin", "Porphine"], axis=0)
y_train = y.drop(["(p-Br)4-TPP", "5,10-NO2-etioporphyrin I", "Deuteroporphyrin-IX-DME", 
                  "N-CH3-Octaethylporphyrin", "Porphine"], axis=0)
X_test = X.loc[["(p-Br)4-TPP", "5,15-NO2-etioporphyrin I", "Deuteroporphyrin-IX-DME", 
                  "N-CH3-Octaethylporphyrin", "Porphine"]]
y_test = y.loc[["(p-Br)4-TPP", "5,10-NO2-etioporphyrin I", "Deuteroporphyrin-IX-DME", 
                  "N-CH3-Octaethylporphyrin", "Porphine"]]
from sklearn import linear_model
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Получаем коэффициент детерминации:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_pred = lm.predict(X_train)
r2_score(y_train, y_pred)
```

Пытаюсь получить значение q2 для leave-one-out перекрестной проверки:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
loo_lm = LinearRegression(lm, LeaveOneOut())
loo_lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
loo_lm.score(X_train, y_train)
```

Но получаю такое же значение как и для коэффициента детерминации для тренировочной выборки.

Другой способ посчитать q2:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cvs=cross_val_score(lm, X_train, y_train, cv=21)
cvs
mean_cross_val_score = cvs.mean()
mean_cross_val_score
```

выдает ошибку: UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.

Пожалуйста, помогите посчитать q2 для leave-one-out перекрестной проверки!

PS Примеры X и y. Вот X:

```
    Eig02_EA(dm)    MATS1e  HOMO-LUMO_Gap   SpMax4_Bh(p)    SAdon
compound                    
(m-Cl)4-TPP 0.00    -0.040  2.74    3.86    33.6
(o-Cl)4-TPP 0.00    -0.040  2.80    3.86    33.6
(o-F)4-TPP  0.00    -0.026  2.75    3.84    33.6
(p-Cl)4-TPP 0.00    -0.040  2.69    3.86    33.6
```

Вот y:

```
compound
(m-Cl)4-TPP                                  1.908485
(o-Cl)4-TPP                                  1.924279
(o-F)4-TPP                                   1.851258
(p-Cl)4-TPP                                  1.851258
```

Comment: можете объяснить чего вы хотели добиться этой строкой кода: `loo_lm = LinearRegression(lm, LeaveOneOut())` ?

Comment: выполнить loo перекрестную проверку для модели lm

Comment: вы вызываете конструктор класса `LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None)` и передаете ему в качестве параметров: `fit_intercept=lm` и `normalize=LeaveOneOut()` - по-моему это совсем не похоже на перекрестную проверку и не имеет никакого отношения к LOO ;)

Comment: спасибо, за замечание. Пожалуйста, напишите, как надо

Comment: попробую ответить на вопрос когда будет больше свободного времени...

Comment: жду с нетерпением Вашего ответа

Comment: посмотрите на пример использования `loo` [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1096864/211923)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовавшись советами MaxU и CrazyElf, собрал вот такой код:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
score_list = []
loo = LeaveOneOut()
skipped = 0
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.values[train_index], y.values[test_index]
    lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_lm = lm.predict(X_test)
      skipped += 1
      continue
    score = score(np.array(y_test)[y_lm], np.array(y_lm)[y_lm])
    score_list.append(score)
print(np.mean(score_list))
```

Однако выдает ошибку

````
    skipped += 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent"```
````

Comment: На какой строке ошибка? И честно говоря я не понимаю зачем вы LeaveOneOut используете, вы понимаете, что вы по сути пытаетесь сделать или просто где-то прочитали о LeaveOneOut где-то?

Comment: Ошибка не про строки, а про столбцы. Сходу не вижу, где вы обращаетесь к столбцам

Comment: ошибка - на 7й строке.

Comment: про LOO знаю не по наслышке. я вообще достаточно давно занимаюсь QSAR моделированием. раньше использовал специальный софт. теперь он недоступен, и я решил освоить scikit-learn.

Comment: Ага, так я и думал. Возьмите y.values[train_index], y.values[test_index]

Comment: А если и с X будут проблемы, то X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index] потому что скорее всё-таки в этой строке проблемы мне кажется могут быть, у Pandas Series колонок ведь не должно быть.

Comment: Только всё же вот фильтрация вам тут не нужна, это я для специфического случая применения KNN этим кодом отвечал, так что всё, что касается y_lm_filt вам не нужно в коде.

Comment: Вам вообще нужно просто использовать cvs=cross_val_score(lm, X_train, y_train, cv=LeaveOneOut)

Comment: не, cvs я уже пробовал. выдает ```UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.
  warnings.warn(msg, UndefinedMetricWarning)``` и ```array([nan, nan ... nan])```

Comment: @CrazyElf а по поводу приведенного кода и по поводу строки ```skipped += 1``` есть идеи?

Comment: Так эта строка со skipped и следующая которая continue вам не нужна :)  Питон ругается на то, что отступ неправильный, но вам эти строки в принципе не нужны тут, их надо было убрать вместе с if в котором они изначально были. Но в итоге вы получите то же самое предупреждение и nan-ы вместо score. Код из моего ответа делает в точности тоже самое используя cross_val_score, только короче.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать примерно так:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

lr = LinearRegression()
loo = LeaveOneOut()
cvs=cross_val_score(lr, X_train, y_train, cv=loo)
print(cvs)
print(cvs.mean())
```

А что касается ошибки

> UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than
>   two samples.

Вы понимаете, как работает `LeaveOneOut` в качестве кросс-валидации? Он по очереди откладывает из выборки **один** сэмпл, тренирует модель на остальной части выборки и потом считает score на этом отложенном сэмпле. При этом метрика `sklearn.metrics.r2_score`, которая видимо используется в данном случае для вычисления score, считает, что по одному сэмплу её нельзя вычислять. Так что вам надо определиться - либо метод кросс-валидации неправильный, либо метод вычисления score. Они между собой несовместимы.

Comment: пишет ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_iter_test_masks'```

Comment: Покажите хотя бы несколько строк ваших X и y, а то так сложно гадать

Comment: добавил X и y в основной пост

Comment: А, я протормозил, LOO надо же инстанциировать наверняка, попробуйте исправленный код. Я потом попробую с вашими данными, позже.

Comment: выдает просто список из 26 nanов (cvs). и еще один nan - cvs.mean(). (((

Comment: А теперь прочитайте, что я написал там про вашу ошибку. Значит код правильный. Просто метод кросс-валидации Leave One Out несовместим с метрикой R^2. Вы раньше в своём моделировании именно так делали, как сейчас пытаетесь?

Comment: И когда вы делали cv=21 в коде это был тот же самый Leave One Out по сути. Вам надо либо вручную метрику R^2 считать, если это и правда возможно для одного сэмпла, либо менять метрику на другую, либо метод кросс-валидации менять.

Comment: В cross_val_score можно передать свою функцию вычисления score, если вам нужно именно так всё-таки. scoring=

Comment: вот [тут](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/302777947_A_quantitative_structure-property_relationship_QSPR_study_of_singlet_oxygen_generation_by_pteridines) лежит моя статья 2016 года. там есть формула для вычисления q2

Comment: извините, я очень тупой. моя строка со скорингом: ```cvs=cross_val_score(lr, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=loo) ```. выдает ошибку ```ValueError: continuous is not supported```

Comment: ну да, понятно. accuracy - это для классификационных моделей

Comment: Мне кажется зря вы всё-таки держитесь так за LOO. Обычной кросс-валидации в 3-5-7 фолдов бывает достаточно вполне. В некоторых случаях можно и в 20 фолдов её делать, но не тогда, когда у вас так мало сэмплов.

Comment: да это понятно. по-большому счету этот показатель сомнительный для оценки качества построенной модели. но, так уж повелось, в научных статьях по QSAR его все приводят. это хороший тон

Comment: может быть, вот [тут](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11434) есть ключик к пониманию того, что делать?

Comment: Так эта дискуссия и привела к тому, что scikit-learn выдаёт в итоге nan если один сэмпл. Там если с нижнего сообщения дальше по ссылке пройти как-раз и обсуждают, что надо это сделать в библиотеке. И сделали. Эта метрика неустойчива. Вам надо ещё раз подумать - зачем вы всё это затеяли. Раз люди этот случай признали ненадёжным и отказались считать метрику по одному сэмплу, значит это не зря. Единственное что можно сделать - написать свою функцию вычисления метрики. Но тут думать надо. Может если туда передать y_mean свою как-то по всему train, то будет устойчивее. Если я правильно вообще понял

Answer (score 0):

В итоге на researchgate мне посоветовали вот такой код:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score as r2
# Assuming you have X_train and y_train in a correct form
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lm, X_train, y_train, cv=len(X_train))
r2_score = r2(y_pred,y_train)
r2_score
```

Не знаю, правильно ли это. Но вроде работает.

Comment: А, ну в принципе логично. Только я так понимаю тут усредняются предсказания по Leave One Out кросс-валидации и берётся score от усреднённого предсказания, а не как делали вы - усредняли score по каждому фолду. В принципе, это выход. А с точки зрения методологии вам должно быть виднее, правильно это или нет. :)